# Windows 10 Desktop PC "losing track" of screens, and they go/stay black

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors, desktop-computer

I have a (10 year-old?) self-built Desktop PC, with 2 Dell monitors (U2412M), one connected DVI-DVI, on HDMI-DVI.

Intermittently I'll turn one or both screens off, for some reason, and leave them off for 1-10 hours. (Perhaps to watch a film, perhaps someone's sleeping in the sitting room, whatever).

When I turn it/them back on, moderately frequently ... but not *always* ..., Windows doesn't seem to notice, and the screen(s) stay entirely blank. The computer is still entirely functional, and is behaving as though there are 2 monitors, but it doesn't display anything on the monitor(s).

If one of the monitors is "alive", then I can drag stuff off that monitor, onto the blank monitor - it doesn't hit the edge of the only monitor that is displaying.

If I can successfully get Windows to reset the monitor display, then that fixes it.
E.g. if I go into display settings and switch it from "1 display on each monitor" to "duplicate one display on both monitors", then the "blank" monitor will suddenly wake up and be fine (and then I can set it back to normal settings, and it remains fine).
Likewise, if both screens are blank, then if I disconnect one of them, then the other pops back to life.

Very occassionally, the same symptoms ("screens stop displaying, but everything else seems fine") will happen semi-spontaneously, though I think it's often associated with some program (often Chrome or Firefox) having crashed.

What the hell is going on!? And how do I fix it!?

Comment: How are they connected? Basically, the puter thinks the monitors are there & doesn't realise they were switched off or indeed back on. That's likely to be the "I'm awake" signal failing to be sent by the displays. Some connection methods are worse than others for that, In order VGA, HDMI, DVI, DisplayPort.

Comment: @Tetsujin added to question. Both Monitors receive DVI jacks, one going to computer on DVI, one on HDMI.

Comment: OK, DVI ought to behave [if it's DVI-D not A], HDMI is … errmm… poor in most respects. tbh, I'm surprised windows even still thinks they are there at all. It is simply not within design spec to be able to physically switch off a display & have it continue to be recognised as present. The 'bug' you are seeing is actually that all your other windows should immediately jump back inside your main display if you switch another screen off. The display is 'gone'. The computer ought to respond to that & isn't doing, so your issue is actually technically the opposite of your described problem.

Comment: Can you get modern drivers for the ten year old machine?

Comment: A potential problem could be HDCP encryption. If the handshake fails the received image data can't be decrypted and thus the screen stays black. May be the old cables aren't the best now or the drivers don't reinitialize the connection properly.