# Change Win-10 display settings on command line or via C#

Tags: windows-10, command-line, multiple-monitors, display-settings

Context: [Windows 10 Desktop PC "losing track" of screens, and they go/stay black](https://superuser.com/questions/1662795/windows-10-desktop-pc-losing-track-of-screens-and-they-go-stay-black)

I want to mimic the effect of "changing the Windows Display config" (see end for the specific UI navigation) on a command line, so that I can set it up such that I can easily run the command/script with Keyboard only, without access to the monitors.

All I need is a script or exe that can do this, and then either I can use my keyboard's has programmable F-Keys, or I could do:

- Win-Key
- type "cmd"
- Enter
- type "reset_screens.sh/.cmd/.ps1/.exe/.whatever"
- Enter

So, how can I reproduce the effect of that UI interaction without the UI?

UI Sequence:

- Minimise everything down to desktop
- Context Menu for desktop background
- "Display Settings"
- Scroll down to "Multiple Displays".
- In the drop down change from "Extend these displays" to "Duplicate these display".
- *What happens after that is irrelevant, as long as it then gets reversed*

Comment: These seem like promising links, but I haven't yet identified anything specificaly in them that would solve it :( (And I know that link-only answers aren't considered appropriate :D)

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36664/Changing-Display-Settings-Programmatically
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/233411/how-do-i-enable-a-second-monitor-in-c

Answer (score 3):

There is a command that can do it called: DISPLAYSWITCH.exe
Note this is the program that opens when you press Windows+P

I don't know how it works internally, but you can call it from C#.

The WIN32 command for updating these display settings seems to be: SetDisplayConfig

Syntax
DISPLAYSWITCH /Option

Options

```
   /internal    Switch to use the primary display only.
   1            All other connected displays will be disabled. 

   /clone       The primary display will be mirrored on a second screen.
   2        

   /extend      Expand the Desktop to a secondary display.
   3            This allows one desktop to span multiple displays. (Default).

   /external    Switch to the external display only (second screen).
   4            The current main display will be disabled.
```

Comment: Ooh! An exciting new development ... I'll take a look at this at some point in the (hopefully not too distant future) and accept if it works for me.

Comment: Feel free to intermittently ping me if I haven't come back to accept / refute this after a few weeks :)

Comment: This is so handy, thanks